# Resource not found when attempting to send voice message through AWS Pinpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, error-handling, aws-pinpoint

I currently have a Node.js service to send a voice call through AWS Pinpoint. However, I'm getting a `Resource not found` response after making a call. I tested with `PinpointSMSVoice.sendVoiceMessage` which succeeds in making the call. The one that doesn't work is `Pinpoint.sendMessages`. My request object looks like this:

```
{
  ApplicationId: 'project-id',
  MessageRequest: {
    Addresses: {
      ['destination-number']: {
        ChannelType: 'VOICE',
        Substitutions: {
          // Using a template
        }
      }
    },
    MessageConfiguration: {
      VoiceMessage: {
        LanguageCode: 'en-US',
        OriginationNumber: 'origination-number'
      }
    },
    TemplateConfiguration: {
      VoiceTemplate: {
        Name: 'voice-template
      }
    }
  }
};

pinpoint.sendMessages(requestObj, callback);
```

I should note that I am not in sandbox mode, it was approved and moved to production mode. I have tested the same setup with SMS which works perfectly well. I'm not quite sure what the difference is between `PinpointSMSVoice.sendVoiceMessage` and `Pinpoint.sendMessages`, except for the fact that `Pinpoint.sendMessages` allows me to set a template. Any ideas on what else I could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm encountering the same issue. It works using PinPointSMSVoice client, but that won't let me use a template. I've also tested this using V3 of the AWS JS SDK, which modularizes the clients @aws-sdk/client-pinpoint-sms-voice and @aws-sdk/client-pinpoint, but the behaviour is the same. It works uses the same tempplate in the 'Test Message' feature in the console, so seems to be a JS SDK issue. I suggest you raise the issue with JS SDK team https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking a look into that, I'll raise the issue with the team!

Comment: which version of v3 did you test out?

Answer (score 0):

When you use PinPoint to perform the **sendVoiceMessage** operation, you need to set the content type to **application/json**. If you do not, you get this exception. To see an example (this is the AWS Java API), see this Github URL:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/pinpoint/src/main/java/com/example/pinpoint/SendVoiceMessage.java

Comment: I was able to send a voice call with `sendVoiceMessage` from (`pinpointSMSVoice`) without setting the content type. The one I'm having problems with is `sendMessages` from (`pinpoint`, different client from the other one). This is the specific client https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javascript/example_code/pinpoint. The docs list voice as an option here https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/pinpoint.html#Pinpoint.Client.send_messages. Any ideas on why this client isn't working for voice?

Comment: My colleague tested this with the new JS client. Looks like there is an issue. Recommend that you open a ticket with the JavaScript SDK team.- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3